# How to extract only the first occurrences of rows corresponding to a specific column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a pandas dataframe of over 100,000 which is already sorted accordingly, however given this sorted dataframe I'm trying to only extract the rows associated with the first occurrence of a specific column. I give an example below where the dataframe df can be considered the sorted dataframe I already have

```
d = {'id': [10,32,4,10,11,5,32,10], 'A': ['S', 'F', 'R', 'Z','X','T','S','B]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

print(df)
```

| id | A |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | S |
| 32 | F |
| 4 | R |
| 10 | Z |
| 11 | X |
| 5 | T |
| 32 | S |
| 10 | B |

And my objective is to perform some kind of vectorization or slicing to df where we only keep the rows associated with the first occurrence of each unique id in the column "id". So the resulting dataframe should be the following:

| id | A |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | S |
| 32 | F |
| 4 | R |
| 11 | X |
| 5 | T |

since the the rows that have id = 10, 32 after the first occurrence are removed. Furthermore, since the df I originally have is over 100,000 I'd like to make it as fast possible so I'm thinking some form of vectorization would be the fastest way but I'm not sure exactly how to perform that.

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates('id')`?

Comment: Try `result = df.groupby(by='id').first().reset_index()`

Comment: @k33da_lets_debug Yup that worked, thank you so much!!